# How to get combine results of all models using sphinx search

Tags: django, sphinx

Recently i have implemented django-sphinx search on my website.
It is working fine of each separate model. 
But now my client requirement has changed. He wants to display result as
"Title" first from  matching query then description and soon.
But i think sphinx give result specific to each model but not gives combine
result of all models.

So can anyone help me how to display "Title" from matching query as first
and then description and soon from results of all models.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. Maybe you need to get result like queryset of real objects:
[,  ...etc] ?